# PYTHONPATH not set up before rc.local executed

Tags: boot, python

I've got a Python script that I want to be started on boot. Putting a command in rc.local attempts to run the script, but fails because the script can't find the libraries on which it depends. These libraries are in a non-standard location. Normally, this isn't a problem because I specify these locations by setting up the PYTHONPATH environment variable in /etc/environment.

I tried specifying PYTHONPATH in rc.local (a non-optimal solution anyway because I'd like to specify it system-wide for all users in one place, ie, /etc/environment) which partly cures the problem. But it's still failing for one library (Quick2Wire) where the included file is in a sub-dir. PYTHONPATH includes the path:

```
/usr/local/lib/cr/python/quick2wire-python-api/src
```

The actualy include file is:

```
/usr/local/lib/cr/python/quick2wire-python-api/src/quick2wire/i2c.py
```

Normally, Python has no problem knowing it needs to look in the quick2wire sub-dir.

I guess I can setup a special version of PYTHONPATH in rc.local just to get this script to run and then have the version in /etc/environment replace it. Just wondered if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: Have you considered using a virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

```
export PYTHONPATH=</blah/blah> ; python /usr/local/lib/cr/python/quick2wire-python-api/src/quick2wire/i2c.py
```

the above should do the trick.

Else you can create a script ( .sh ) with above content and call the script from rc.local ;)